# Why my ubuntu repository updation using gui not updating system cache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, caching, repository, updates

I am trying to update the Ubuntu repository cache using GUI after removing the following repo:

deb http://repo.tld/ubuntu distro component

I removed it from the other software section located in the software and updates the application.
After clicking the **reload** button, the system cache should be updated but it throws an error:

error message: **error while refreshing cache**
the whole image is:

**pk-client-error-quark: E: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy- security InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to 10.217.32.229:8181 (10.217.32.229). - connect (111: Connection refused)) E: http://repo.tld/ubuntu distro InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to 10.217.32.229:8181 (10.217.32.229). - connect (111: Connection refused)) E: http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to 10.217.32.229:8181 (10.217.32.229). - connect (111: Connection refused)) E: http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to 10.217.32.229:8181:) E: http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to 10.217.32.229:8181:) (319)**

please assist me. I need to solve the problem nor my job will be at stake as a technical writer.